# Swift return struct with generic

Tags: swift, generics, struct

I'm having a issue using generics.

I have a protocol : `SectionReusableView`

```
public protocol SectionReusableView {

    associatedtype AdapterType: SectionReusableViewAdapter

    var adapter: AdapterType? { get set }

}
```

I have this struct `TableViewSectionReusableSupplementraryViewFactory`

```
public struct TableViewSectionReusableSupplementraryViewFactory<T: SectionReusableView> {

    public var adapter: T.AdapterType

    public init(adapter: T.AdapterType) {

        self.adapter = adapter

    }

}
```

What I want is create a function which will return **Any** `TableViewSectionReusableSupplementraryViewFactory` of specified type `T`

```
func supplementaryViewFactory<T>(at index: Int,
                              within tableView: UITableView) -> TableViewSectionReusableSupplementraryViewFactory<T>? {

    let adapter = self.adapter(at: index, within: tableView)
    let reuseIdentifier = self.reuseIdentifier(at: index)

    switch reuseIdentifier {

    case AwesomeReusableView.AwesomeReusableViewReuseIdentifier:

        guard let adapter = adapter as? AwesomeReusableViewAdapter else { return nil }

        return TableViewSectionReusableSupplementraryViewFactory<AwesomeReusableView>(adapter: adapter)

    default:

        return nil

    }

}
```

But I get this error and I don't know how to bypass

```
error: cannot convert return expression of type
'TableViewSectionReusableSupplementraryViewFactory<AwesomeReusableView>' to return
type 'TableViewSectionReusableSupplementraryViewFactory<T>?'
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't how generic functions are used.

Generic functions get specialized on the `T` essentially. Creating a brand new function (at compile time) to use in the special cases where it gets called with the various types.

If you notice in your example you aren't actually specializing the function by making use of the `T`. You are giving it an explicit return type which may, or may not, match the unknown `T`, the compiler doesn't know and therefore can't allow it.

Lets imagine if it did, say you were calling this like `let factory = supplementaryViewFactory<FOO>(...)` but inside the method it actually returns a `TableViewSectionReusableSupplementraryViewFactory<BAR>`! OOPS you've got a major problem now

Here would be an converted example:

```
func supplementaryViewFactory<T>(...) -> TableViewSectionReusableSupplementraryViewFactory<T>? where T: SectionReusableView  {

    let adapter = MyCoolAdapterClass()

    guard let converted = adapter as? T.AdapterType else { return nil }

    return TableViewSectionReusableSupplementraryViewFactory<T>(adapter: converted)

}
```

Couple things to notice, first the type of `TableViewSectionReusableSupplementraryViewFactory` gets specialized by the type needed. What that means is that the type where this is called is going to end up determining what the `T` is.

So you'd have to have something like:

```
let factory : TableViewSectionReusableSupplementraryViewFactory<AwesomeReusableView>? = supplementaryViewFactory(...)
```

A final note, Swift is a very type safe language, If you were hoping to allow your factory method to return an unknown specialized type it would probably be best to abstract further to just returning a raw protocol. In which case you don't need to care what the backing type is.

Comment: Thanks :) But I can't do it like it, the class which call the supplementaryViewFactory doesn't know which Type to specialize.

That's why I wanted to return an "Any" TableViewSectionReusableSupplementaryViewFactory

Comment: @Pwyll28, I figured as much, in which case I would suggest steering away from generics and just use plain jane protocols. Or, if you want to keep the generics, have your main struct implement a protocol which would then be the return type of your factory method and remove the `<T>` from it

Comment: But the point of this method is to return a factory of <AwesomeView> or <TestView> or <WhateverViewIDesigned> and use the factory to implement my UITableViewDelegate/Datasource Method in an other class @utahwithak